# Insert key,value list in dataframe

Tags: python

I have a nested list which contains key, value in every row. I'd like to know how to put this list data into a dataframe.

```
[ [ [key1,value1], [key2,value2], [key3,value3], [key2,value20] ], 
[ [key1,value4], [key3,value6], [key4,value2] ] ]
```

`key1` is the primary key in the data.

The following data contains 2 rows, some key,values are missing in data.
How can I put these data into dataframe

```
key1     key2     key3    key4     key2
value1   value2   value3  NaN      value20
value4   NaN      value6  value2   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely new answer based on additional information provided:

```
x=[[['key1','value1'], ['key2','value2'], ['key3','value3'], ['key2','value20']], 
   [['key1','value4'], ['key3','value6'], ['key4','value2']]]

def make_df(sublist):
    keys=[i[0] for i in sublist]
    keys=[str(keys[i])+'_'+str(keys[i:].count(keys[i])-1) for i in range(len(keys))]
    vals=[[i[1]] for i in sublist]
    df=pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,v in zip(keys, vals)})
    return df

df_list=[make_df(i) for i in x]

for i in df_list:
    print(i)

   key1_0  key2_1  key3_0   key2_0
0  value1  value2  value3  value20
   key1_0  key3_0  key4_0
0  value4  value6  value2

def combine_dfs(df_lst):
    df=df_lst[0]
    for i in df_lst[1:]:
        df=pd.concat([df,df_list[1]], axis=0, sort=True)
    return df

new_df=combine_dfs(df_list)

new_df

    key1_0  key2_0  key2_1  key3_0  key4_0
0   value1  value20 value2  value3  NaN
0   value4  NaN     NaN     value6  value2
```